# Is there any alternative to async.waterfall?

Tags: node.js, async-await

Can I write my own code to simulate `async.waterfall` without using it? I am trying to do using `then` but unable to achieve that.

Comment: Please show us an example of what you have tried.

Comment: Can`t post code here, it`s an enterprise code. can you just give me an alternative? I do not want to use the ```async``` library.

Comment: It is simple: No code, no help. As it is your question is just asking for code. And it is way to broad. We don't deliver code or type down documentations here... You can't share your code with us? Then we can't share our code with you...

Comment: read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to do a waterfall:

```
function waterfall(funcs) {
  return funcs.reduce((acc, func) => acc.then(func), Promise.resolve());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use newer Node.js version with async/await, you can do something like this:

```js
async function waterfall(fns){
  let previous = 0;
  for (let i=0; i < fns.length; i++) {
    console.log(previous, 'start');
    previous = await fns[i](previous);
    console.log(previous, 'end');
  }

  console.log('The last result is', previous);
}

const fnsForWaterfall = [input => Promise.resolve(input + 3), input => Promise.resolve(input + 1)]

waterfall(fnsForWaterfall);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BinayakShankar - thanks I have updated it a bit to not include directly the fns into waterfall function